# Obtain types of variadic types in template template classes

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose we have a class

```
template <int ... values>
struct foo;
```

now I have a function

```
template<typename foo_type, typename U>
void bar(foo_type a, U b);
```

where `foo_type` is basically `foo`. My issue is that, I do not want the variable `a` in the `bar` function. I want to be able to call the function like so

```
bar<foo<6,5,7,8,0>>(42);
```

but have all the parameters of `foo` available to me in `bar`. I tried changing the function to

```
template<template<int...> class foo_type, int ... args, typename U>
void bar(U b)
```

but this simply does not work. How can I do this? How can I change `bar` to the above way and still access the parameters in `foo`? Basically I want to do generic computation on those list at runtime

```
// within the body of bar
constexpr int[sizeof...(args)] = {args...};
```

where `args` is parameters of `foo`.

Comment: How are you going to access the individual `values` in `foo`?

Comment: Basically `bar` can call another function with parameters of `foo`. Sorry I didn't make it clear.

Comment: How about `template <typename foo_type, typename U>
void bar(U b);`?

Comment: But why the `foo`? Why not just `template <int ..., typename U> void bar(U)` and call it like `bar<1, 2, 3>(b)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe, the question is about extracting template arguments from given `foo` type? If I am correct, here is the solution.

You will have to partially specialize a helper class, like following:

```
template <int ... values>
struct foo { };

template<class T>
struct bar_helper {};

template<int... values> struct bar_helper<foo<values...> > {
  template<class T> static void bar(T ) {
      // Use values... here
  }
};



template<class foo_type, class U>
void bar(U b) {
  bar_helper<foo_type>::bar(b);
}


void check() {
 bar<foo<2, 3, 4, 5, 6> >(42);
}
```

Comment: Perfect, what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

How opposed are you to having `foo` be an argument? Personally, I like having everything be an argument. Just wrap it in an empty type:

```
template <class T> struct tag_type { using type = T; };
template <class T> constexpr tag_type<T> tag{};
```

So that you can still template on the `ints...`:

```
template<int... Is, typename U>
void bar(tag_type<foo<Is...>> a, U b) {
    constexpr int stuff[sizeof...(Is)] = {Is...};
    // ...
}
```

Instead of calling `bar<foo<6,5,7,8,0>>(42);` you'd call `bar(tag<foo<6,5,7,8,0>>, 42);`, which is close enough.

---

To get exactly what you want, you can forward the former call to the latter:

```
namespace details {
    template<int... Is, typename U>
    void bar(tag_type<foo<Is...>> a, U b) {
        constexpr int stuff[sizeof...(Is)] = {Is...};
        // ...
    }
}

template <typename foo_type, typename U>
void bar(U b) {
    details::bar(tag<foo_type>, b);
}
```

And now it's the best of both worlds.

Comment: To do what the OP wants, just have the normal bar call this `bar` with a `tag_type<foo_type>`.  (Move this `bar` to a `namespace details` to make it unambiguous in the case of overly complex overloads)

Comment: @Yakk Thanks for the fix, and added that as a suggestion.